# Shinken Monitoring : How to set timeout for a service check explicitly?

Tags: nagios, shinken

From the  ***shinken.cfg*** this values can be set..,

```
  service_check_timeout=60
  timeout_exit_status=3
```

But as it is getting applied globally for all the service checks..,

Is it possible to have service specific timeout and timeout_exit_status..?

Comment: https://github.com/naparuba/shinken/issues/2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Follow this link](https://github.com/naparuba/shinken/issues/2011)

Timeout can be set at the command level